# How to add some μs delay inside the for loop for this STM32 code?

Tags: stm32, pwm, timer

I'm using HAL library and the finction called HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback to update DAC output at the end of each pulse. Here is the related section of the code:

```
void HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

   if(htim -> Instance == TIM3)
   {
      if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
     {
          ValDAC1 = ValDAC1 + step_DAC1;

          if(ValDAC1 > 4095)
          {
              ValDAC1 = 4095;
          }
          DAC1->DHR12R1 = currValDAC1;
          pulsCount++;
          if(pulsCount > numP)
          {
              HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
          }
     }
   }

   if(htim -> Instance == TIM8)
   {
      if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2)
     {
          if(pulsCount > numP)
          {
              HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT(&htim8, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

              for(int i = 0; i<ValDAC1; i++)
              {
                  DAC1->DHR12R1 = ValDAC1 - i;
                  //Need some uS delay here 
              }
              
              DAC1->DHR12R1 = 0;

          }
     }
   }
}
```

And after some number of pulses the DAC goes to zero as in the for loop above. But I need a delay between each for iteration as shown in the comment as "Need some uS delay here" above. I dont need precision there but some microseconds of delay. How could that be possible?

Comment: Note that a few us might be a significant number of cpu clocks depending on the actual device. Sometimes it might be advantageous to utilise a timer and/or any event mechanism to relieve the cpu of wasteful delays.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care if it blocks (OP doesn't say)
You can insert another for loop with a `nop` inside.

Put this line somewhere in the file (compiler specific).
`asm volatile("nop");`
or
`__asm__("nop");`
[This ST Forum](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000LecFOSAZ/creating-delay-using-asmnop) says to use the latter syntax

Then inside your for loop add this loop
`for( int idx = MAX_LOOP; idx != 0; idx-- )`
`{`
   `nop;`
`}`

Comment: "nop" means nothing inside the for loop? If so I must have tried output but  didnt make difference. But I will double check it and let you know.

Comment: @cm64 the compiler may optimize it away. You can do some temp variable calculation too. Basically crunch numbers for a bit.

Comment: I usually use `asm volatile("nop");` to force inclusion.

Comment: @cm64 See the updates

Comment: But where do you add:  asm volatile("nop"); ? I tried inside main and outside it didnt work. I get compiler error. Where should that line be? What do you mean by "somewhere in the file"?

Comment: @cm64 The `asm` syntax is compiler specific.  I added another form to the answer.  You should look in the documentation for your compiler/IDE.

Comment: @cm64 As for the "where do I put it?"  It's a type of define, so it is usually best placed towards the top of the file, not inside a function. You could also place it in a header file.

Answer (score 4):

**DWT_Initialization() Function**

```c
uint32_t DWT_Delay_Init(void)
{
    /* Disable TRC */
    CoreDebug->DEMCR &= ~CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // ~0x01000000;
    /* Enable TRC */
    CoreDebug->DEMCR |=  CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // 0x01000000;
 
    /* Disable clock cycle counter */
    DWT->CTRL &= ~DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; //~0x00000001;
    /* Enable  clock cycle counter */
    DWT->CTRL |=  DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; //0x00000001;
 
    /* Reset the clock cycle counter value */
    DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
 
    /* 3 NO OPERATION instructions */
    __ASM volatile ("NOP");
    __ASM volatile ("NOP");
    __ASM volatile ("NOP");
 
    /* Check if clock cycle counter has started */
    if(DWT->CYCCNT)
    {
       return 0; /*clock cycle counter started*/
    }
    else
    {
      return 1; /*clock cycle counter not started*/
    }
}
```

**DWT_Delay_us() Function**

```c
// This Function Provides Delay In Microseconds Using DWT
 
__STATIC_INLINE void DWT_Delay_us(volatile uint32_t au32_microseconds)
{
  uint32_t au32_initial_ticks = DWT->CYCCNT;
  uint32_t au32_ticks = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq() / 1000000);
  au32_microseconds *= au32_ticks;
  while ((DWT->CYCCNT - au32_initial_ticks) < au32_microseconds-au32_ticks);
}
```

**DWT_Delay_ms() Function**

```c
// This Function Provides Delay In Milliseconds Using DWT
 
__STATIC_INLINE void DWT_Delay_ms(volatile uint32_t au32_milliseconds)
{
  uint32_t au32_initial_ticks = DWT->CYCCNT;
  uint32_t au32_ticks = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq() / 1000);
  au32_milliseconds *= au32_ticks;
  while ((DWT->CYCCNT - au32_initial_ticks) < au32_milliseconds);
}
```

Sources:

- https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BGkxmCSQR/stm32l462-delay-in-a-microsecondus
- https://deepbluembedded.com/stm32-delay-microsecond-millisecond-utility-dwt-delay-timer-delay/

Comment: Which timer does this use?

Comment: It uses the DWT (data watchpoint trigger) registers.

Comment: DWT_Delay_Init(void) function is fine in main.c but for DWT_Delay_us fucntion I had to remove __STATIC_INLINE when inside main.c. Where should a function with __STATIC_INLINE prefix stay?

Comment: You either have to _(a)_ include a header which specifies `__STATIC_INLINE`, _(b)_ define it yourself `#define __STATIC_INLINE static inline`, or _(c)_ simply replace __STATIC_INLINE with `static inline`.

Comment: What purpose does the `-au32_ticks` have in the loop condition: `while ((DWT->CYCCNT - au32_initial_ticks) < au32_microseconds-au32_ticks);`? Would this not lead to delays that are too short by 1µs? And the `volatile` qualifier for the argument seems unnecessary since CYCCNT should be volatile itself already?

Comment: @radioflash The `volatile` qualifier is necessary to prevent the compiler from making "clever" optimizations to the argument itself. I can only assume that the purpose of `-au32_ticks` is to make up for the time lost before entering the `while` loop. If I had an STM32 at hand, I'd do some measurements with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @Seir I understand what the volatile qualifier does, but my point is that it's not necessary on the argument, only the register access itself. You DONT want it on the argument because that just forces the compiler to emit needlessly convoluted code. Just see for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/sPKd97fdv (you'd only get a problem with the optimizer if you'd remove the volatile qualifier from the CYCCNT access, too).

Comment: @radioflash You're right. It's sufficient that `CYCCNT` is declared as `volatile`. Btw, thanks for linking to the 'Compiler Explorer'. Seems like quite a useful online tool.